# typescript - getting error trying to implement an interface inside a class

Tags: typescript

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong... i'm trying to use an interface inside a class an initialize it, but i'm getting this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
at new User (eval at setTimeout (main.js:493), <anonymous>:4:24)
at eval (eval at setTimeout (main.js:493), <anonymous>:9:14)
at setTimeout (main.js:493)
```

here is what i'm trying to do:

```
interface UserInterface {
    name: string
    email: string
}

class User {
    id: string
    data: UserInterface

    constructor(){
        this.data.name = ''
        this.data.name = ''
        this.id = ''
    }
}

const user = new User()

console.log(user.data)
```

tks people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned a value to `this.data` yet, so it is `undefined`.

Instead, assign it like so:

```
this.data = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
};
```